# Reusable data sources in Swift w/ different cell types

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

Based on this [article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/reusable-data-sources-in-swift/) I have created a reusable data source for `UICollectionView` as follows :-

```swift
final class CollectionViewDataSource<Model>: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {
  typealias CellConfigurator = (Model, UICollectionViewCell) -> Void
  var models: [Model] = []

  private let reuseIdentifier: String
  private let cellConfigurator: CellConfigurator

  init(reuseIdentifier: String, cellConfigurator: @escaping CellConfigurator) {
    self.reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier
    self.cellConfigurator = cellConfigurator
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let model = models[indexPath.item]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cellConfigurator(model, cell)
    return cell
  }
}
```

I have then extended this class so I can provide 'cell specific' setup based on the type of model

```swift
extension CollectionViewDataSource where Model == HomeFeedItem {
  static func make(reuseIdentifier: String = "FEED_ARTICLE_CELL") -> CollectionViewDataSource {
    return CollectionViewDataSource(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, cellConfigurator: { item, cell in
      (cell as? FeedArticleCell)?.render(with: item)
    })
  }
}

extension CollectionViewDataSource where Model == HomeFeedAlertItem {
  static func make(reuseIdentifier: String = "FEED_ALERT_CELL") -> CollectionViewDataSource {
    return CollectionViewDataSource(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, cellConfigurator: { item, cell in
      (cell as? FeedAlertCell)?.render(with: item)
    })
  }
}
```

This is working perfect, however, each of these cells has a different design but does in fact accept very similar properties (as do the other cells) - because of this I was thinking of creating a simple `FeedItemModel` and mapping these properties prior to rendering my feed. This would ensure anywhere I rendered a feed item, I was always dealing with the same properties.

With that in mind I tried to create something like :-

```swift
extension CollectionViewDataSource where Model == FeedItemModel {
  static func make(reuseIdentifier: String = "FEED_ARTICLE_CELL") -> CollectionViewDataSource {
    return CollectionViewDataSource(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, cellConfigurator: { item, cell in
      switch item.type {
      case .news: (cell as? FeedArticleCell)?.render(with: item)
      case .alert: (cell as? FeedAlertCell)?.render(with: item)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

This however falls down as the `reuseIdentifier` field is no longer correct if `item.type` is `.alert`.

How can I refactor this pattern to allow me to use different cells types with the same model? Or should I abandon this approach and stick to a different model for each cell type regardless of the input properties being the same?

Comment: does your Model equals to FeedItemModel for .alert?

Comment: Yes, I `FeedItemModel` is a generic model and I am mapping the relevant values from each type of model to that, so the feed items should only need to use `FeedItemModel` regardless of their type

Comment: ok, what means "This however falls down as the reuseIdentifier field is no longer correct", you have a crash here? or wrong identifier?

Comment: The identifier is wrong, as each cell is registered with it's own identifier, so on reuse `FeedArticleCell` and `FeedAlertCell` use the value `make(reuseIdentifier: String = "FEED_ARTICLE_CELL")` - as they are different cells I would like to set the `reuseIdentifier` based on `item.type` which each model has.

Comment: It does not crash, rather just renders the wrong cell type as I assume it uses the `reuseIdentifier` to prepare the cell.

Comment: you can add reuseIdentifier to your item.type and remove `reuseIdentifier: String = "FEED_ALERT_CELL"`, it will be `CollectionViewDataSource(reuseIdentifier: item.type.reuseIdentifier,...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a protocol such as

```swift
protocol FeedRenderable {
  var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
}
```

Then ensure the `Model` type conforms to `FeedRenderable`.

You can then refactor your `CollectionViewDataSource` to

```swift
final class CollectionViewDataSource<Model>: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource where Model: FeedRenderable {
  typealias CellConfigurator = (Model, UICollectionViewCell) -> Void
  var models: [Model] = []

  private let cellConfigurator: CellConfigurator

  init(_ cellConfigurator: @escaping CellConfigurator) {
    self.cellConfigurator = cellConfigurator
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let model = models[indexPath.item]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: model.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cellConfigurator(model, cell)
    return cell
  }
}
```

Notice the following changes

```swift
final class CollectionViewDataSource<Model>: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource where Model: FeedRenderable {
....
init(_ cellConfigurator: @escaping CellConfigurator) 
....
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: model.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
....
```

You can then ensure whatever model is passed in sets its `reuseIdentifier` based on the `item.type` property

```swift
extension GenericFeedItem: FeedRenderable {
  var reuseIdentifier: String {
    switch type {
    case .news: return "FEED_ARTICLE_CELL"
    case .alert: return "FEED_ALERT_CELL"
    }
  }
}
```

Your extension then becomes

```swift
extension CollectionViewDataSource where Model == GenericFeedItem {
  static func make() -> CollectionViewDataSource {
    return CollectionViewDataSource() { item, cell in
      (cell as? FeedArticleCell)?.render(with: item)
      (cell as? FeedAlertCell)?.render(with: item)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a associate identifier to your `FeedItemModelType`

```
var reuseIdentifier: String {
    switch self {
        case .news: return "NEW_CELL"
        case .alert: return "ALERT_CELL"
   }
}
```

And your factory method would look like this

```
extension CollectionViewDataSource where Model == FeedItemModel {
  static func make() -> CollectionViewDataSource {
    return CollectionViewDataSource(reuseIdentifier: item.type.reuseIdentifier, cellConfigurator: { item, cell in
      switch item.type {
      case .news: (cell as? FeedArticleCell)?.render(with: item)
      case .alert: (cell as? FeedAlertCell)?.render(with: item)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This produces `Use of unresolved identifier 'item'` as `item` does not exist in the scope of the `make() -> CollectionViewDataSource`

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a second generic type for the cell

```
final class CollectionViewDataSource<Model, CellType : UICollectionViewCell>: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    typealias CellConfigurator = (Model, CellType) -> Void
    var models: [Model] = []

    private let reuseIdentifier: String
    private let cellConfigurator: CellConfigurator

    init(reuseIdentifier: String, cellConfigurator: @escaping CellConfigurator) {
        self.reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier
        self.cellConfigurator = cellConfigurator
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return models.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let model = models[indexPath.item]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CellType
        cellConfigurator(model, cell)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this require me to use a datasource for each type of feed item?

Comment: You can use it in the same way as you do but you get a static cell type along with the static model type